# Using Cookies To Access HTML

Tags: python, post, cookies

I'm trying to access a site (for which I have a login) through a `.get(url)` request. However, I tried passing the cookies that should authenticate my request but I keep getting a `401` error. I tried passing the cookies in the `.get` argument like so

```
requests.post('http://eventregistry.org/json/article?action=getArticles&articlesConceptLang=eng&articlesCount=25&articlesIncludeArticleConcepts=true&articlesIncludeArticleImage=true&articlesIncludeArticleSocialScore=true&articlesPage=1&articlesSortBy=date&ignoreKeywords=&keywords=soybean&resultType=articles', data = {"connect.sid': "long cookie found on chrome settings")
```

(Scroll over to see how cookies were used. Apologies for super long URL)

Am I approaching the cookie situation the wrong way? Should I login in with my username or password instead of passing the cookies? Or did I misinterpret my Chrome's cookie?

Thanks!

Comment: Your session id that is stored in the cookie will problably change every time you login

Comment: Is there a way to pass the cookie to a `get` request by logging in?

Comment: No, when you login you use a post request.

Comment: Even if you could, it wouldn't work. The cookies change everytime you login to a webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
import requests

payload = {
    'email': '###@gmail.com',  #find the right name for the forms from HTML of site
    'pass': '###'}

# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('loginURL')
    r = s.get('restrictedURL') 
    print(r) #etc
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that we've updated the package to access the Event Registry data so now you can actually make requests without using the cookies. Instead you can just append the parameter apiKey=XXXX in the url. You can find details on the documentation page:

http://eventregistry.org/documentation